# Text Processing: how can I extract the right fields from a list of strings?

Tags: python, regex, text-processing

I want to extract six fields from `content_list` and put them into a dataframe. The fields are: `Seq. #`, `Name`, `Coding Instructions`, `Target Value`, `Selections`, and `Supporting Definitions`. However, the regex I have to get the metadata object,is not giving me `Seq. #` for each item in the list, and missing a few other items, so when I go to subset it, it gives me an index out of range error. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can you help me? Thank you!

```
import re 
import pandas as pd

content_list = ['\nSeq. #:\n2031', 'Name:\nSSN N/A\nThe value on arrival at this facility\nTarget Value:\nSelection Text\nDefinition\nNo\nYes\nSelections:\n(none)\nSupporting Definitions:\nIndicate the number created and automatically inserted by the software that uniquely identifies this patient.\nCoding Instructions:\nOnce assigned to a patient at the participating facility, this number will never be changed or reassigned to a different patient. If the \npatient returns to the same participating facility or for followup, they will receive this same unique patient identifier.\nNote(s):', '\nSeq. #:\n2040', 'Name:\nNCDR Patient ID\nThe value on arrival at this facility\nTarget Value:\n(none)\nSelections:\n(none)\nSupporting Definitions:\nAn optional patient identifier, such as Medical Record Number, that can be associated with the patient.\nCoding Instructions:\nThis element is referenced in The Joint Commission AMI Core Measures, AMI-1 through AMI-5. AMI-7, 7a, 8, 8a and AMI-9.\nNote(s):', '\nSeq. #:\n2045', "Name:\nOther ID\nN/A\nTarget Value:\n(none)\nSelections:\n(none)\nSupporting Definitions:\nIndicate the patient's date of birth.\nCoding Instructions:\nThis element is referenced in The Joint Commission AMI Core Measures, AMI-1 through AMI-5. AMI-7, 7a, 8, 8a and AMI-9.\nNote(s):", '\nSeq. #:\n2050', "Name:\nBirth Date\nThe value on arrival at this facility\nTarget Value:\n(none)\nSelections:\n(none)\nSupporting Definitions:\n© 2007, American College of Cardiology Foundation\n3/31/2014\nPage 2 of 137\nEffective for Patient Discharges January 01, 2015\nCoder's Data Dictionary\nNCDR® ACTION Registry®-GWTGŽ v2.4\nA. Demographics\nIndicate the patient's sex at birth.\nCoding Instructions:\nThis element is referenced in The Joint Commission AMI Core Measures, AMI-1 through AMI-5. AMI-7, 7a, 8, 8a and AMI-9.\nNote(s):", '\nSeq. #:\n2060', 'Name:\nSex\nThe value on arrival at this facility\nTarget Value:\nSelection Text\nDefinition\nMale\nFemale\nSelections:\n(none)\nSupporting Definitions:\nIndicate if the patient is White.\nCoding Instructions:\nIf the patient has multiple race origins, specify them using the other race selections in addition to this one.\nThis element is referenced in The Joint Commission AMI Core Measures, AMI-1 through AMI-5. AMI-7, 7a, 8, 8a and AMI-9.\nNote(s):', '\nSeq. #:\n2070', 'Name:\nRace - White\nThe value on arrival at this facility\nTarget Value:\nSelection Text\nDefinition\nNo\nYes\nSelections:\nWhite (race)\n:\nHaving origins in any of the original peoples of Europe, the Middle East, or North Africa.\nSource:\nU.S. Office of Management and Budget. Classification of Federal Data on Race and Ethnicity\nSupporting Definitions:\nIndicate if the patient is Black or African American.\nCoding Instructions:\nIf the patient has multiple race origins, specify them using the other race selections in addition to this one.\nThis element is referenced in The Joint Commission AMI Core Measures, AMI-1 through AMI-5. AMI-7, 7a, 8, 8a and AMI-9.\nNote(s):','\nSeq. #:\n1040', 'Name:\nTransmission Number\nN/A\nTarget Value:\n(none)\nSelections:\n(none)\nSupporting Definitions:\nVendor Identification (agreed upon by mutual selection between the vendor and the NCDR) to identify software vendor. Vendors \nmust use consistent name identification across sites. Changes to Vendor Name Identification must be approved by the NCDR.\nCoding Instructions:', '\nSeq. #:\n1050', "Name:\nVendor Identifier\nN/A\nTarget Value:\n(none)\nSelections:\n(none)\nSupporting Definitions:\nVendor's software product name and version number identifying the software which created this record (assigned by vendor). \nVendor controls the value in this field. Version passing certification/harvest testing will be noted at the NCDR.\nCoding Instructions:", '\nSeq. #:\n1060', "Name:\nVendor Software Version\nN/A\nTarget Value:\n(none)\nSelections:\n(none)\nSupporting Definitions:\n© 2007, American College of Cardiology Foundation\n3/31/2014\nPage 136 of 137\nEffective for Patient Discharges January 01, 2015\nCoder's Data Dictionary\nNCDR® ACTION Registry®-GWTGŽ v2.4\nZ. Administration\nThe NCDR Registry Identifier describes the data registry to which these records apply. It is implemented in the software at the time \nthe data is collected and the records are created. This is entered into the schema automatically by software.\nCoding Instructions:", '\nSeq. #:\n1070', 'Name:\nRegistry Identifier\nN/A\nTarget Value:\n(none)\nSelections:\n(none)\nSupporting Definitions:\nRegistry Version describes the version number of the Data Specifications/Dictionary, to which each record conforms. It identifies \nwhich fields should have data, and what are the valid data for each field. It is the version implemented in the software at the time \nthe data is collected and the records are created. This is entered into the schema automatically by software.\nCoding Instructions:', '\nSeq. #:\n1080', 'Name:\nRegistry Version\nN/A\nTarget Value:\n(none)\nSelections:\n(none)\nSupporting Definitions:\nReserved for future use.\nCoding Instructions:', '\nSeq. #:\n1200', "Name:\nAuxiliary 0\nN/A\nTarget Value:\n(none)\nSelections:\n(none)\nSupporting Definitions:\n© 2007, American College of Cardiology Foundation\n3/31/2014\nPage 137 of 137\nEffective for Patient Discharges January 01, 2015\nCoder's Data Dictionary\nNCDR® ACTION Registry®-GWTGŽ v2.4\nZ. Administration"]

sequence_list = []
metadata = []
for i in content_list:
    metadata = list(filter(None, re.split("\s*(?:Seq. #:|Name:|Coding Instructions:|Target Value:|Selections:|Supporting Definitions:)\s*", i)))
    sequence_list.append([metadata[0], metadata[1], metadata[2], metadata[3], metadata[4], metadata[5]])

df = pd.DataFrame(sequence_list, columns = ['Seq #:','Name','Coding Instructions','Target Value','Supporting Definitions','Selections'])
df['Seq #:'] = df['Seq #:'].astype(int)
df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the items in `content_list` with a newline and then split the resulting string with a double newline to get paragraphs, that you can later parse with a matching regex like

```py
pattern = r'(?s)^Seq\. #:\s*(.*?)\nName:\s*(.*?)\nTarget Value:\s*(.*?)\nSelections:\s*(.*?)\nSupporting Definitions:\s*(.*?)(?:\nCoding Instructions:\s*(.*))?$'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mj0HQO/1/). It seems like `Coding Instructions` can be missing, so it is made optional in the regex.

Python demo:

```py
sequence_list = []
pattern = r'^Seq\. #:\s*(.*?)\nName:\s*(.*?)\nTarget Value:\s*(.*?)\nSelections:\s*(.*?)\nSupporting Definitions:\s*(.*?)(?:\nCoding Instructions:\s*(.*))?$'
for i in re.split(r'\n{2,}', '\n'.join(content_list)):
    m = re.match(pattern, i.strip(), re.S)
    if m:
        sequence_list.append(m.groups())
df = pd.DataFrame(sequence_list, columns = ['Seq #:','Name','Coding Instructions','Target Value','Supporting Definitions','Selections'])
```

Note that each paragraph is only parsed if the regex matches, and if it does, match `.groups()` data is used to populate the dataframe later.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm afraid the content_list was not fully representative of my data (I've updated it), as when I run your code, the data frame I get has the seq number correct, but it has issues with the rest of the variables

Comment: @Adri Do you mean there can be `Note(s)` field in the data?

Comment: There can but I'm not looking at those. For example, this is the first row I get: Seq#: 2031, Name: 'SSN N/A\nThe value on arrival at this facility', Coding Instructions: Selection Text\nDefinition\nNo\nYes, Target Value: (none), Supporting Defitions: , Selections: None

Comment: @Adri So what do you expect?

Comment: @Adri The regex that will consider `Notes` is https://regex101.com/r/AftYHk/1/